# Google app engine ignores my custom db property when I bulkload data?

Tags: google-app-engine, validation, bulkloader

### The problem:

When I store the data with bulkloader the method DecimalProperty.get_value_for_datastore is never called so, when I store 5.4 in the datastore saves exactly like this: 5.4; This should be passed thought get_value_for_datastore and convert to an integer like this: 54000; Because I need 4 digits after decimal: 5.4 * 10000 = 54000; then back 54000/10000 = 5.4

---

I have a model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from gae.properties.decimal_property import DecimalProperty
Articles:
    price = Decimal(4)
```

---

Decimal class

```
from decimal import Decimal
from google.appengine.ext import db

class DecimalProperty(db.Property):
    """
    Allows Python's decimal.Decimal type to be stored in the datastore as an
    integer.  Takes care of putting the decimal point in the right place.
    """
    data_type = Decimal

    def __init__(self, dec_places, verbose_name=None, name=None, default=None,
                 required=False, validator=None, choices=None, indexed=True):
        super(DecimalProperty, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, default,
            required, validator, choices, indexed)
        self.__quantize_exp = Decimal('10') ** -dec_places
        self.__store_mul = Decimal('10') ** dec_places

    def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_inst):
        dec = super(DecimalProperty, self).get_value_for_datastore(model_inst)
        if dec is None:
            return None

        dec = dec.quantize(self.__quantize_exp)
        return int(dec * self.__store_mul)

    def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None

        return Decimal(value) / self.__store_mul

    def validate(self, value):
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, Decimal):
            raise db.BadValueError("Property %s must be a Decimal or string." % self.name)
        return super(DecimalProperty, self).validate(value)

    def empty(self, value):
        return (value is None)
```

---

My bulkloader is:

```
from google.appengine.ext import bulkload
from google.appengine.api import datastore_types
import datetime

class ArticleLoader(bulkload.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkload.Loader.__init__(self, 'Article', [
            ('price', str)
        ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bulkload.main(ArticleLoader())
```

And my csv file is like this:

```
 5.4
```

---

Notes:

If I put in the bulkloader Decimal:

```
from google.appengine.ext import bulkload
from google.appengine.api import datastore_types
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

class ArticleLoader(bulkload.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkload.Loader.__init__(self, 'Article', [
            ('price', Decimal)
        ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bulkload.main(ArticleLoader())
```

I get this error:

```
Loading from line 1...error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\bulkload\bulkload_deprecated.py", line 306, in LoadEntities
    new_entities = loader.CreateEntity(columns, key_name=key_name)
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\bulkload\bulkload_deprecated.py", line 160, in CreateEntity
    entity[name] = converter(val)
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 881, in __setitem__
    datastore_types.ValidateProperty(name, value)
  File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore_types.py", line 1477, in ValidateProperty
    'Unsupported type for property %s: %s' % (name, v.__class__))
BadValueError: Unsupported type for property price: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

---

### VERY DIRTY SOLUTION:

```
('price', to_decimal(4))

def to_decimal(dec_places):
    def converter(s):
        val = int(round(Decimal(s), dec_places) * 10 ** dec_places)
        return val

    return converter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bulkload data with the bulkloader, your model definitions are not loaded or used - data is loaded directly into the datastore using the low-level API. As a result, none of your model code is called either. Your 'very dirty solution' is the right way to go about this.

Comment: thanks ;) but I think they should be able to somehow be DRY, by reusing the code defined in the model for consistence and not by-passing all validations, anyways.. but thanks ;)